# How to get rid of the derivatives in the solution?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I have this system equations:

```
sys2 = {(4 i Cosh[2 x])/Gamma[1 + α] - Subscript[a, 0][x]/
   Gamma[1 + α], -(Subscript[a, 1][x]/Gamma[1 + α]) + (i (Subscript[a, 0]^′′)[x])/
   Gamma[1 + 2 α], -(Subscript[a, 2][x]/
    Gamma[1 + α]) + (i Gamma[1 + α] (Subscript[a, 1]^′′)[x])/
   Gamma[1 + 3 α], (4^(-2 α) i Sqrt[π] (Subscript[a, 2]^′′)[x])/
  Gamma[1/2 + 2 α]}
solutionset = 
 Solve[sys2 == 0, {Subscript[a, 0][x], Subscript[a, 1][x], Subscript[a, 2][x]}]
```

I get this output after solving the system of equations:

```
{{Subscript[a, 0][x] -> 4 i Cosh[2 x], 
  Subscript[a, 1][x] -> (i Gamma[1 + α] (Subscript[a, 0]^′′)[x])/Gamma[1 + 2 α], 
  Subscript[a, 2][x] -> (i Gamma[1 + α]^2 (Subscript[a, 1]^′′)[x])/Gamma[1 + 3 α]}}
```

The derivatives in the right-hand side of the rules may be replaced by the expression for the previous solutions, the `Subscript[a, 0]''[x]` by the solution for `Subscript[a, 0]` and
the `Subscript[a, 0]''[x]` by the solutions for `Subscript[a, 1]` and `Subscript[a, 0]`.

How can I get the output without derivatives?

This is an idea of what I want:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: (1) There is no equal sign in your "equations". (2) Your input has derivatives, so if you used `Solve`, your output should have derivatives.  Or did you use `DSolve`.  -- Please post complete code to clarify.

Comment: I cannot figure out what is the question. Are you wanting to solve a system of ODE's?

Comment: I want to obtain a_0, a_1 and a_2.

Comment: @BahramAgheli In one sense, you already have obtained a_0, a_1 and a_2.  See if my answer has them in the **form** you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what the OP wants is for the derivatives in the right-hand sides of the rules to be replaced by their values given by back-substitution.

```
exprToFN = HoldPattern[(f_)[v_] -> expr_] :> (f -> (expr /. v -> # &));

MapAt[# //. (First@solutionset /. exprToFN) &, solutionset, {1, All, 2}]
(*
  {{Subscript[a, 0][x] -> {4 i Cosh[2 x]}, 
    Subscript[a, 1][x] -> {(16 i^2 Cosh[2 x] Gamma[1 + α])/Gamma[1 + 2 α]}, 
    Subscript[a, 2][x] -> {(64 i^3 Cosh[2 x] Gamma[1 + α]^3) / 
       (Gamma[1 + 2 α] Gamma[1 + 3 α])}}}
*)
```

Comment: Many many  thanks.

Comment: @BahramAgheli You're welcome.

Comment: Excuse Me, for this:    solutionset = 
 Solve[sys2 == 0, {Subscript[a, 0][x, y], Subscript[a, 1][x, y], 
   Subscript[a, 2][x, y]}]

Comment: @BahramAgheli I can't check without complete code, but maybe `exprToFN = 
 HoldPattern[(f_)[u_, v_] -> expr_] :> (f -> (expr /. {u -> #1, v -> #2} &))`?